# Serve Next.js build from a Node/Express server in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, next.js

I currently have my Node/Express server hosted on Heroku and it serves my bundled React code from Vite like so (`vite build` outputs `dist` folder)

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.use('*', (req, res, next) =>
  // in deployment we send index.html for all additional paths not defined by our express routes
  // react router pushes different paths to window url
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
);
```

The `vite build` command creates a `dist` folder with an `index.html` file at the root, so it makes sense how my SPA is served by Express in this case. However, I plan to move my client side code over to Next.js for some of the server side rendering benefits, while still having the bundle served by my express backend. But the Next.js build command generates a `.next` directory with a much different structure and no `index.html` at the root. I notice in the server/app folder there is something similar but I am not sure if that's what I am supposed to be serving.

Has anyone done this before - serving a bundled Next app from their Express server in production - and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're probably building the wrong config: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports